# Can't turn off x-ray mode

Tags: wireframe

for some reason I can't get out of the x-ray or wireframe mode. I know to find the overlays button, but whatever I do, I can't get to see my object in solid mode.
[image]

Answer (score 4):

Check *Object Properties > Viewport Display > Display As*  dialog. The *Display As* mode should be switch to *Solid*.[image]